# ArrayIndexOutOfBound when parsing int from string array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I am new to StackExchange so I will do my best at making this question as understable as possible. I am trying to take all Integers from a String Array created from a .csv file. The file looks like so,

- type,name,untiprice,quantity
- Bitem,toothpaste,1.50,2
- Fitem,eggs,2.50,1

and so on...

Everything works perfectly until I try to add the numbers to the array. The output returns a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I made the MAX_SIZE of this array = 100. The amount of integers in the text file is no more than 8. I don't understand why this is problem is happening. Are my for-loops completely wrong or is there more to the problem?

```
public static void loadNums()
{
    String inputFile=("/Users/user1/Desktop/list.csv");
    File file = new File(inputFile);
    Scanner scanFile = null;

    try{
        scanFile =new Scanner(file);
    }catch(NumberFormatException | FileNotFoundException exception){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    if (scanFile != null)
    {
        String[] numStrs = scanFile.nextLine().split(",");
        int[] num = new int[numStrs.length];
        for (int i =0; i <numStrs.length; i++)
        {
            if (i ==0)
            {
                System.out.println("Numbers");
            }
            else 
            {
                numStrs = scanFile.nextLine().split("\\d+.,\\d+");
                for (int j =0; j <numStrs.length; j++)
                {
                    num[i] = Integer.parseInt(numStrs[i]);
                }
                System.out.println(num[i]);
            }

       }
  }
```

Comment: You might want to consider a CSV reader package like my SimpleCSV http://256stuff.com/sources/simplecsv/

Comment: @Gray I will defintly use this in the future. But I also want to see if I can do it without this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to parse the second array `numStrs` with the first index i :

```
num[i] = Integer.parseInt(numStrs[i]);
```

So instead to that use this, change the `numStrs[i]` with `numStrs[j]`:

```
num[i] = Integer.parseInt(numStrs[j]);
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks you! I changed index i with j and it fixed the out of bounds error. However, I received a NumberFormatException. Would it be possible that my .split("\\d+.,\\d+"); is not done correctly?

Comment: i think so that, let me check and i will replay

Comment: @P.Jacques yes your regex is not correct for that you get this error try this to see what i mean `public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    String s = "Bitem,toothpaste,1.50,2";
    String[] numStrs = s.split("\\d+.,\\d+");
    System.out.println(numStrs.length);
    for (int j = 0; j < numStrs.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(numStrs[j]);
    }
}` the result is `Bitem,toothpaste,1.` and this not an integer

Comment: Okay, got it. I will read more on split method formatting and do my best to fix this. Thank you again.